# How can I make Excel a template only in Office 365/Share point

Tags: microsoft-excel

When using tools such MS Forms (for surveys) or Mural/Miro I can create a template.

The template allows others to duplicate them for their own use with impacting the original.

I have an Excel, which so far, we use a naming convention of the file which is

`_PLEASE_CREATE_A_COPY_BEFORE_MAKING_CHANGES.xls`

Obviously there is risk because some one may simply not do this!

Is it possible to create 'duplicate' only versions of Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Within Share point, you may have to edit the share options and un check the allow editing option

Answer (score 0):

You can try IRM, which can be found at this link for details: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/set-up-irm-in-sp-admin-center?view=o365-worldwide